# Unix shell : substring with regular expression

Tags: regular-expression

I have this text:

```
1234
```

I want to use a regex to select all except the first digit (in this case 1) -
so a pattern that selects

```
234
```

How can I do this?
I can't use variables, only regex. And also I can't delete the first digit. Only a regex that select all the string except the first number.

Comment: Maybe you want `sed 's/\([1234]\)\([1234][1234][1234]\)/ first is \1, rest is \2/'` but it is very hard to tell from your question. Please clarify.

Comment: add some more information in your question. Is it only digit ? or alphanumeric ?.. only one word/column in your text..etc

Comment: Please could you clarify what you're trying to do?  Where do you "have" this text (in a file? the output of some command?), and what do you want to happen after you "select" it (save it in a variable?  redirect it to another file, or command? copy it to the clipboard?)

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: `a=1234; echo "${a:1}"` also returns `234`. It really depends what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

The standard command to apply regexps to string arguments is `expr` with its `:` operator. It understands standard *Basic Regular Expressions*. It outputs 1 or 0 depending on whether the regexp matches or not unless the regexp has at least one capture group in which case it outputs what was matched by the first capture  group. One peculiarity of `expr`'s `:` is that the regexp is implicitly anchored at the start as if it started with `^`. So:

```
text=1234
expr "x$text" : "x.\(.*\)"
```

We prefix both the text and regexp with `x` (arbitrary), as otherwise the command would fail if the content of `$text` happened to be an `expr` operator, or at least some `expr` operator, the ones being a problem depending on the implementation. Example:

```
$ text='('
$ expr "$text" : ".\(.*\)"
expr: syntax error: expecting ')' instead of ‘.\\(.*\\)’
$ expr "x$text" : "x.\(.*\)"

$ text=index
$ expr "$text" : ".\(.*\)"
0
$ expr "x$text" : "x.\(.*\)"
ndex
```

The first `.` matches the first character of `$text` which is not output as it's not inside the capture  group. Then we capture the rest `.*` being 0 or more characters, as many as possible for output.

The exit status will be non-zero if the regexp doesn't match (`$text` is empty or starts with something that can't be interpreted as a character) or if the output is the number `0` (and depending on the `expr` implementation, some of its various other spellings like `00`, `-0`...) or the empty string.

But in any case, you don't need to run `expr` or use regexps for that. Standard shell parameter expansion operators can do it:

```
text=1234
printf '%s\n' "${text#?}"
```

Where `${var#pattern}` expands to the content of `$var` where the leading part that matches `pattern` has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text is in the file `file`, the following `sed` command will remove the first digit on each line of the file and output the result:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]//' file
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file
123
1234
alpha123
a1b2c3
```

```
$ sed 's/[[:digit:]]//' file
23
234
alpha23
ab2c3
```

---

If the string is in a variable, you don't really need a regular expression.  It would be enough with

```
${string/[[:digit:]]/}
```

in `bash`.

```
$ string=alpha123
$ printf '%s\n' "${string/[[:digit:]]/}"
alpha23
```

If you're only interested in removing a digit if it occurs in the first position, you may use the standard parameter substitution

```
${string#[[:digit:]]}
```

as in

```
$ string=1234
$ printf '%s\n' "${string#[[:digit:]]}"
234
```